# Skip rows above and below desired data in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I have multiple csv file that looks something like this:

```
>>> print(df)
    x x.1 x.2 x.3  ... Unnamed: 33 Unnamed: 34 Unnamed: 35 Unnamed: 36
0   x   x   x   x  ...           x           x           x           x
1   x   x   x   x  ...           x           x           x           x
2   x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3   x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
4   x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
5   x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
6   x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
7   x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
8   x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
9   x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
10  x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
11  x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
12  x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
13  x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
14  A   A   A   A  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
15  B   B   B   B  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
16  C   C   C   C  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
17  D   D   D   D  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
18  E   E   E   E  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
19  F   F   F   F  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
20  x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
21  x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
22  x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
23  x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
24  x   x   x   x  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN

[25 rows x 37 columns]
```

There are a lot of different types of data in this csv file, but the only data I require is that labelled `A-F`. I have a large amount of these csv files, so what I want to do is merge them together but only with the data that I want from them.

I have two approaches, one better than the other.

**(1)** The data I want pretty much always occurs on row `14-19` and is 4 columns long. So what I was thinking each time I read in one of these csv files I can skip rows above `14` and below `19` however I am unsure how to do this?

Something like this `data = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows=[0:14])` however I also want to skip any rows after 19? Is there a way to just load in rows `14-19` with just columns `0-4`?

**(2)** My second idea I am not sure if possible but in case the data doesn't appear on row `14-19` in one file, maybe I can get python to somehow search for the data I want and that will get rid of any errors of taking the wrong rows?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

pandas has an additional param, `nrows`, which can be used to read only a specified number of rows

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=list(range(14)), n_rows=6)
>>> df
    x x.1 x.2 x.3  ... Unnamed: 33 Unnamed: 34 Unnamed: 35 Unnamed: 36
0   A   A   A   A  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1   B   B   B   B  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2   C   C   C   C  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3   D   D   D   D  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
4   E   E   E   E  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
5   F   F   F   F  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: The skip rows is not actually working? I get the same result skipping the first 3 rows as I do skipping the first 7 rows, any idea why this is?

Comment: Sorry yes I made a mistake. The parameter should be `skiprows` not `skip_rows`. Also, the docs of pandas point out that `skiprows` is "Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file." So this should be a list, or an int. I have adjusted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

following your second idea 'in case the data doesn't appear on row 14-19 in one file':

```
 #getting the desired rows
df_desired = data.loc[  (data['x'] == 'A') | (data['x'] == 'B')|(data['x'] == 'C') | (data['x'] == 'E')| (data['x'] == 'F')]

 #getting the first 4 columns
df=df.ix[:,[0:4]]
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting invalid syntax on the semicolon in 0:4 ?

Comment: i don't have your actual data to test out, but the second line of code is simply getting the first 4 columns, can you try diff ways?